# FileMaker Server 11 Advanced (Mac) + Remote Network Access?

Tags: macos, remote-access, filemaker

My company uses FileMaker as its database solution. We just got a Mac Mini Server, and we are using FileMaker Server 11 Advanced to host our database over our internal network. We are planning on making a lot of changes to our database's structure, but it's not always going to be posible for us to physically be at the office to do so; therefore, my boss wants me to figure out how we can remotely access our hosted database. The only system in this process that's a Mac is the server - we use Windows machines - so that will have to be taken into account.

Any and all suggestions will be welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do remote development all the time using FileMaker Pro connected directly to FileMaker Server on port 5003, and it works great. It also helps spot performance problems early during the development process, because if it's slow when you develop it, you've got an architecture issue that needs to be fixed.

Citrix / Terminal services is of course another good option, but it's certainly not a requirement.

Comment: Sounds promising. So, does FMServer connect itself to 5003 by default, and I just forward that? What's my next step after I forward the port?

Comment: The client communicates with the server on port 5003. There are some additional ports for administration and scanning the local network, but 5003 is all you need for basic client-server communication. You should be able to go to File->Open Remote in FileMaker Pro, add the IP address of the server, and see the hosted files.

Comment: Awesome. Here's the question, though - how do I secure this? Any way to set up a secured login? The last thing I need is for the creepy black-hat across the road to see the open port and get access to our company's database (and yes, I am referencing a real person and situation).

Comment: In FileMaker Server admin there is an option to encrypt communications - simply check the box to "Secure connections to FileMaker Server" - note that if you have older FileMaker clients you will need to install the client SSL update in order to see hosted files.

Of course you want to have accounts setup on your databases as well. 

I would also suggest enabling the option to Display Only the Databases Each User is Authorized to Access box so that all of your databases don't show to the outside world.

Comment: Hey - after a year or so of learning how servers and networks actually work, I finally understand the advice that I've been given here - my only question now is the question of how to secure access to the databases. Right now, if I open port 5003, anybody can access the files hosted on the server. How can I put some sort of authentication on this?

Comment: Authentication is done using FileMaker accounts, which are set up in the File->Manage->Security section. If you need encryption, enable that on the server as Andy suggested. Be aware that there is a noticeable performance impact from encryption (just like with https or anything else).